# Existence of a certain equivariant map from the sphere to a compact Lie group of lower dimension.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, equivariant-maps

Is there a natural number $n$, a compact Lie group $G$ of dimension less than $n$ and a nontrivial (non-constant) continuous map $f:S^n \to G$  with $f(-x)=f(x)^{-1}$?
If yes, is there a map with this property which is not a null homotopic  map?

Answer (score 3):

What about$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&S^2&\longrightarrow&S^1\\&(x,y,z)&\mapsto&\bigl(\cos(\pi x),\sin(\pi x)\bigr)?\end{array}$$

Comment: Is there a non null homotop one?

Comment: @AliTaghavi I don't know.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I am thinking to a $G$ which does not admit an equivariant map as in the question, except the contstant map.

Comment: @AliTaghavi If you want an equivariant map, you first explain which group action is given in $S^n$.

Comment: @ChoF  The  action on the  sphere  is the antipodal  action and  the  action on the  group is by inversion. I think   it is  indicated in the  question "$f(-x)=f(x)^{-1}$".Right?